# How I can access a control inside an ItemTemplate and connect it to a datasource by the time it is initialized?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I know that there are similar questions to this one out there, but I can't seem to find any that address my issue.

I have a `GridView` that is populated with data from my database. The user has the option to delete or edit this data, a pretty standard operation. To insert data into the `GridView`, the user fills out a form and presses the submit button. In the form, there are three textboxes and a `DropDownList`. As you may expect, this means that, inside the `GridView` in edit mode, there are three textboxes and a `DropDownList`. My issue is this: When the user presses the `Edit` button, the application breaks. It says something to the effect of "myDropDownList cannot be loaded because the selected value is not in the list of items."  Basically, the `DropDownList` inside the `EditItemTemplate` in the `GridView` is empty. I have tried to populate it the same way that I populate the other `DropDownList` (the one in the form), but it is not initialized until the `GridView` is put in edit mode. Here is the markup for the `EditItemTemplate`:

I have omitted some code for brevity.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LocationCode" SortExpression="LocationCode">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl_EditLocCode" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLocCode" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Location Code is a required field."
            ControlToValidate="Ddl_EditLocCode" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>' ID="Label5"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the code I have written to populate the `DropDownList` inside the `EditItemTemplate`:

Note that this is the `RowDataBound` event handler.

```
Private Sub Gv_Assignments_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gv_Assignments.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If DataControlRowState.Edit Then
            Dim editLocCodeDdl As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Ddl_EditLocCode"), DropDownList)
            CreateDataSourceForEditDdl(editLocCodeDdl)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub CreateDataSourceForEditDdl(editLocCodeDdl As DropDownList)
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection
        Dim DataReader As SqlDataReader
        Dim listItem As New ListItem
        Using conn.Conn
            conn.Conn.Open()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = conn.Conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "SELECT [location_code], [loc_name] FROM [myTable] ORDER BY [location_code]"
                End With
                DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim locationCode As String
                Dim loc_name As String
                While DataReader.Read()
                    locationCode = DataReader.Item("location_code").ToString()
                    loc_name = DataReader.Item("loc_name").ToString()
                    editLocCodeDdl.Items.Add(New ListItem(locationCode & "-" & loc_name))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Perhaps the `RowDataBound` event handler is not where I should be attempting  to populate the edit mode `DropDownList`... I'm not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: RowUpdating Code**

Here is the `RowUpdating` code:

```
Private Sub Gv_Assignments_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles Gv_Assignments.RowUpdating
        'change the lessonID to the appropriate ID based on the lesson name
        'get the lesson name, then set the label text in the lesson ID column to the correct ID by calling GetLessonID(lessonname)

        Dim lessonNameBox As DropDownList = DirectCast(Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlEditLessonName"), DropDownList)
        'Dim lessonIdLabel As Label = DirectCast(Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("LblLessonID"), Label)
        'Dim ID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
        'lessonIdLabel.Text = GetLessonID(lessonNameBox.SelectedValue)

        Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text = GetLessonID(lessonNameBox.SelectedValue)
        'UpdateLessonID(lessonIdLabel.Text, ID)
    End Sub
```

As you can see, I am doing pretty much nothing in this function. I should add that I used the GridView's smart tag to assign a `SqlDataSource` to the GridView. Every other editable cell gets successfully updated when I edit it in edit mode. For some reason, when I removed this line: `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>'`, the `Ddl_EditLocCode` successfully populated with the desired values, but it failed to update on the back end and front end when I edited it; in fact, it made the value `Null`. Any ideas?

**Edit 2: The SqlDataSource**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_GvAssignments" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DedicatedTerminal_devConnectionString %>' 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [CreatedAssignments] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [CreatedAssignments] ([LessonName], [LessonID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [LocationCode], 
                    [DateAssigned]) VALUES (@LessonName, @LessonID, @StartDate, @EndDate, @LocationCode, @DateAssigned)" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [LessonName], [LessonID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [LocationCode], [DateAssigned] 
                    FROM [CreatedAssignments]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [CreatedAssignments] SET [LessonName] = @LessonName, 
                    [LessonID] = @LessonID, [StartDate] = @StartDate, [EndDate] = @EndDate, [LocationCode] = @LocationCode, 
                    [DateAssigned] = @DateAssigned WHERE [ID] = @ID">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonID" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="StartDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EndDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LocationCode" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="DateAssigned" Type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonID" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="StartDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EndDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LocationCode" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="DateAssigned" Type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code to fill the DropDownList seems ok at first glance. First try removing `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>'`. The error means that the value of `LocationCode` does not exist in the ListItems of `Ddl_EditLocCode`.

And that would seem to make sense since you are adding a ListItem with a value of both the locationCode AND loc_name (`New ListItem(locationCode & "-" & loc_name)`), therefore only the value of LocationCode does not exist and throws the error.

The solution is to create a ListItem with both a Text and Value specified.

```
New ListItem(locationCode & "-" & loc_name, locationCode, true)
```

Comment: Thank you! I got past the first error I was having. Ddl_EditLocCode is now getting the proper values. However, when I click the Update button, it setting the selected item in Ddl_EditLocCode to Null. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code. Are you accessing the correct row?

Comment: Yes I am accessing the correct row. I made the changes you suggested and now, when I select a value from the Ddl_EditLocCode, it is null when I hit the update button. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: I'm not doing anything related to this in the `OnRowUpdating` method. Maybe that's the issue. I'm not sure.

Comment: You should. That is where the action of the update button should be handled. See this excellent tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control

Comment: I am confused about something. Why did Ddl_EditLocCode populate when I removed this line: `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>'`? It populates when I remove that line, but when I update the GridView, the updates aren't saved. I am posting the `RowUpdating` code now.

Comment: `SelectedValue` and the population are not connected. It is only the default value that is set at runtime.

Comment: I have added the code for the SqlDataSource if that helps. Basically, here's what has happened: everything was working fine until I had to edit the drop down lists to include both the number and the name of the location. For example, an item used to look like this: "1234". Now they look like this: "1234-United States." Ever since I edited the dropdownlist in the form, it hasn't worked correctly. I just need to edit the items in the EditItemTemplate dropdown so that they're the same as the ones in the form. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Stop using `SqlDataSource` and start binding in code behind: `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { GridView1.DataSource = mySource; GridView1.DataBind(); }` then it will work since RowDataBound is not called on every PostBack.

Comment: Can I still edit the GridView the way I'm doing it now? Would the user still be able to edit it the same way?